# How to remove datatable from dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset

`.aspx` code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SearchCustomer.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.eyeofheaven.SearchCustomer" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheets/SearchCustomerStyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Search Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
            <!-- Header-->
            <div class="container">
                <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="EyeOfHeaven.aspx">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle active" href="#">Search<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="SearchCustomer.aspx">Search Form(Customer)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="SearchVehicle.aspx">Search Form(Vehicle)</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Search form customer-->
<div id="searchcustomer" class="page-header">
    <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>Search Customer</h3>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="search" size="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer ID">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="Country">
            <option value="select" selected disabled>Search by Country</option>
            <option value="A:C ESTUDIO">A:C ESTUDIO</option>
            <option value="Aaron McEwen-194712">Aaron McEwen-194712</option>
            <option value="Accra">Accra</option>
            <option value="Adoany">Adoany</option>
            <option value="Aduanas">Aduanas</option>
            <option value="Alex Sanchez-259029">Alex Sanchez-259029</option>
            <option value="ALG Consulting-288078">ALG Consulting-288078</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="Algimantas Ramaskevicius">Algimantas Ramaskevicius</option>
        </select>
    </div>  

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="Currency">
            <option value="selected" selected disabled>Search by Currency</option>
            <option value="AUD">AUD (Australian Dollar)</option>
            <option value="EUR">EUR (Euro)</option>
            <option value="GBP">GBP (United Kingdom Pounds)</option>
            <option value="JPY">JPY (Japan Yen)</option>
            <option value="NZD">NZD (New Zealand Dollar)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
<button type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="Button1_Click" id="searchinfo" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search Info</button>
<button type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="Button2_Click" id="Button2" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Information Table-->
<div id="gridview">
    <asp:GridView runat="Server" id="data" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`.aspx` code behind:

```
using MSSQLConnector;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1.eyeofheaven
{
    public partial class SearchCustomer : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MSConnector connector = new MSConnector();
            connector.ConnectionString = "SERVER=xbetasql,52292;UID=username;Password=secret;DATABASE=ATDBSQL;";

            string customer = (this.search.Value);
            string country = (this.Country.Value);
            string idcurrency = (this.Currency.Value);
            string query = null;

            if (country != "select")
            {
                if (idcurrency != "selected")
                {
                    query = "select * from customer where country = '" + country + "' and idcurrency = '" + idcurrency + "'";
                }
                else
                {
                    query = "select * from customer where country = '" + country + "'";
                }
            }
            DataSet selectedData = connector.ExecuteQuery(query);
            DataTable dt = selectedData.Tables[0];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                data.DataSource = dt;
                data.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('No Data Found.')</script>");
            }
        }
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, MSConnector connector, string query)
        {
            DataSet selectedData = connector.ExecuteQuery(query);
            DataTable dt = selectedData.Tables.Remove(dt);
            this.search.Value = "";
            this.Country.Value = "select";
            this.Currency.Value = "selected";

        }
    }
}
```

I have a problem in my code, I want to remove the `datatable` from `dataset` when I click on `Button2_Click` as a reset button for all. But I have an error in my code in here:

```
DataTable dt = selectedData.Tables.Remove(dt);
```

It says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Data.DataTable'

Does passing my `dataset` and `datatable` is the problem on the function `Button2_Click()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need this

```
selectedData.Tables.Remove(dt);
```

But it would be better if you first check that `DataSet` contains the table which you are trying to remove. Also check if the `DataTable` can be removed from `DataSet` as pointed by `Gianni B`.

```
if(selectedData.Tables.Contains(dt.name) && selectedData.Tables.CanRemove(dt))
   selectedData.Tables.Remove(dt);
```

`Remove` method does not return anything. It's `return type` is `void` You are trying to assign a `datatable returned` by `Remove` method while actually it doesn't return anything

Comment: I would also check if my dataset contains the table and if the table can be removed with this: `if(selectedData.Tables.Contains(dt.name) && selectedData.Tables.CanRemove(dt))`

Answer (score 4):

The line which you have written

```
DataTable dt = selectedData.Tables.Remove(dt);
```

is wrong, as remove method does not return anything.

So you need to change your code as

```
selectedData.Tables.Remove(dt);
if(selectedData != null && selectedData.Tables.Count > 0)
{
   DataTable dt = selectedData.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: first of all you need to define your dataset outside of button1 and button2 - means centralized place. in your code, inside button1 you are defining your dataset which is unknown to button2. Then you can write this code inside button2.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DataTable dtDelete = new DataTable();
dtDelete = ds_RecipeData.Tables[0]
if (ds_RecipeData.Tables.Contains(dtDelete.TableName))
    if (ds_RecipeData.Tables.CanRemove(dtDelete))
      ds_RecipeData.Tables.Remove(dtDelete);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same `Datatable` despite entering the `TableName`, so `ds.Tables.Remove` does not work correctly.
This works for me

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

int i = ds.Tables.IndexOf(dt.TableName);

dt = ds.Tables[i];

ds.Tables.Remove(dt);
```

Comment: In this case, it was right - it was just that a return code was being sought, and wasn't what was expected.